# Trim filenames to make them less than 100 characters

Tags: powershell, rename, trim

I got the following files in multiple directories:

```
File 1: Normal file 1.txt
File 2: Normal file 1(1).txt
File 3: Normal file 1 longer file.txt
File 4: Normal file 1 longer file even longer.txt
File 5: Normal File 1 longer file(1).txt
```

I want to trim down the files to ±150 characters (can set value later). For files which have (1), (2), (12) at the end I have currently the following solution in hand.

```
gci -File -Recurse |
    Where BaseName -match '^(.{140})..*(\(\d+\))$' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$Matches[1] + $Matches[2] + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

This works fine because it will not occur that I will have duplicate file names.

But if I use the following script for files without (1), (2), (12) it fails. Because if for example I trim down file 3 till "Normal file 1" I got the error that it already exist.

Used code for that:

```
gci -File -Recurse |
    Where BaseName -match '^(.{140})' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$Matches[1] + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

I was thinking to solve this issue with a code I used for something else, but can't make it work till now. I can happen that a file with (1) also already exist.

```cs
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    where BaseName -match '^(.{140})' |
    Group-Object { $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $Matches[1].TrimEnd() + $_.Extension } |
    foreach {
        $fi = [IO.FileInfo]::New($_.Name)
        $i = 0
        $_.Group | Rename-Item -NewName {
            do {
                $newName = $fi.DirectoryName + "\" + $fi.BaseName + $(if($i){"($i)"}) + $fi.Extension
                $script:i++
            } while (Test-Path $newName)
            $newName
        } -Whatif
    }
```

---

I found out that if I have the following files in my directory:

```
Filename 1 - 45781.txt 
Filename 1(2).txt
Filename 1(3).txt
Filename 1(4).txt
Filename 1(5).txt
Filename 1(1).txt
```

The script will rename the files like:

```
Filename 1.txt 
Filename 1(5).txt
Filename 1(6).txt
Filename 1(7).txt
Filename 1(8).txt
Filename 1(9).txt
```

Comment: instead of trying to calc the counter ... have you thot about simply adding a "somewhat unique" number? this >> `Get-FileHash $File -Algorithm SHA1` <<gives you a 40 character hash. this >> `$File.GetHashCode()` << gives you an 8 character hash. ///// plus, there is always the current time ... [*grin*]

Comment: Your code looks good to me, remember that the `-WhatIf` prevents any renames to take place, so while testing the `do ..while` will show `(1)` for all group members (but he first) as the previous just aren't renamed yet.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey any idea?

Comment: @Nick - um, er, "any idea" about what? your note to LotPings seems to say that you have it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey situation came across in which the solution is not completely sufficient that was the reason for adding some more details in the question as well.

Comment: @Nick - i would STOP using such a silly, self-limiting method of making "unique" file names. [*grin*] remove the `(*)` and add a really simple uniqueness suffix - `(Now - FileTimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds` OR use a simple sequence number without the silly `()` and sort by the sequence number to make sure you increment it properly..